# append div if it is not found child with specific class jquery

Tags: jquery, find, append

I have a div where I want to append another div, only if this child has no an specific class.

```
<div class=container></div>
```

I used `if` in two cases but it doesnt return what expected

```
        if(!$(".container").find(".content").lenght)$("#container").append("
                 <div class=content>hi</div>");

          if(!$(".container").find(".content"))$("#container").append("
                 <div class=content>hi</div>");
```

Comment: Try to use if(!$(".container").find(".content")[0]) {}. And also note, that container is a class, but you are using id-selector #container.

Comment: ok thank you. I updated but in my script, it appends more than one during different clicks using `()[0]`.

Comment: `find(".content").lenght` typo with `length`

Comment: my bad english... cant believe it....Yeah it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your container is a class not an id - should be using `.container` not `#container`

Also, you should be checking if the length is equal to zero as that would mean no content is within the container

```js
if($('.container').find('.content').length == 0)
    $('.container').append("<div class='content'>Some content</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">Some container</div>
```

Comment: it was just a typing error, no results at all at changing it to a class

Comment: @joe well then another thing to try is instead of using `!` you should be checking if the length is equal to 0. Also need to make sure your append statement is using the class selector instead of id